# How to add ISA cards to the Tandy 1000 memory PLUS expansion board

Tags: tandy-1000, isa

I have a Tandy 1000A with a 25-1011 Memory PLUS Expansion Board (maxed out with 384kB). This board has a single 62-pin connector to add low-profile accessories like a mouse/clock card or a modem.

I bought [one of these adapters](https://www.tindie.com/products/cyberneticsys/tandy-1000-exhx-plus-isar-adapter/) and tried a XT-IDE card in it with the back slot cover removed, but it didn't work. I tried the card in both directions. Facing one way, the computer would not boot at all, and emitted a high pitched whine/beep. Facing the other way, the computer booted, but did not start the XT-IDE ROM BIOS. Note that this card still works in this computer when plugged into one of the regular ISA slots.

I think either the adapter I bought is incompatible with this board, or you can't connect just any ISA card there and expect it to work. The adapter says it's for the 1000 EX/HX only, but as far as I know, those models use the same kind of 62-pin connector - basically just an ISA slot in a different format. And does that connector not just go directly to the ISA bus?

Comment: Well, if it say "_for the 1000 EX/HX **only**_", it might actually be incompatible.

Comment: That's true, but you'd think it would be compatible, in theory. It's just an extension of the ISA bus. But I guess the pins on the connector could be mapped to different pins on the slot?